# elasticsearch subquery

Tags: запрос, elasticsearch

Как можно сделать вложенный запрос в `ES` или хотя бы организовать конвейер запрос без пересылки промежуточных данных по сети

Comment: Опишите задачу более подробно. У _ElastiSearch_ есть [пакетная](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) обработка

Comment: Если грубо, то в SQL это вот так выглядит: `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table2)`. 

Пока приходится решать это в 2 запроса.

Comment: Думаю будет проще если будет описание задачи а абстрактный пример. Elasticsearch может производить поиск по нескольким [индексам](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html) и [типам](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html) + фильтрация и агрегация и собственные скрипты если базового функционала не достаточно.

Comment: есть тип где хранится сообщения пользователей на форуме `{Вася:{post: http://my_forum.ru/test/455334434}}`, 
так же есть тип куда пишутся репосты оригинальных сообщений `{Лёша: {post: http://my_forum.ru/test/4553334324, repost: http://my_forum.ru/test/455334434}}`
Задача: узнать сколько раз сообщение Васи было появилось на форуме (тоесть оригинальный пост+все репосты.)